# Can't link c++ libraries using CMAKE and make install

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, ubuntu-16.04

I am having a problem linking two libraries using CMake on linux (ubuntu). I have the following CMake setup.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(lib1)
set(SOURCE_FILES
         source_1.cpp)

# set library output directory
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ../build/)

# Base directory relative to which all includes are
set(BASE_DIR ../)

#include base directory
include_directories ("${BASE_DIR}")

# create a shared library
add_library(lib1 SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})

# make install target
install(TARGETS lib1 DESTINATION /usr/local/lib)
```

For Library 2 we have

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(lib2)
set(SOURCE_FILES
         source_2.cpp)

set(BASE_DIR ../)
#include base directory
include_directories ("${BASE_DIR}")

# create a shared library
add_library(lib2 SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})

# include lib1 library
target_link_libraries(lib2 PUBLIC lib1)

install(TARGETS lib2 DESTINATION /usr/local/lib)
```

Running these with

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(all)

add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(lib2)
```

creates liblib1.so and liblib2.so. liblib2.so depends on liblib1.so (ldd liblib2.so gives the link to liblib1.so in the CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY directory.)

After running

```
 make install
```

I get

```
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/liblib1.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/liblib2.so
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib/liblib2.so" to ""
```

and in /usr/local/lib liblib2.so is no longer linked to liblib1.so.

I tried many reworkings of my cmake file, (e.g. using :

```
 set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "/usr/local/lib")
 set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

but nothing seemed to help. Anyone can explain me how to get the libraries to link after make install?

I did run `ldconfig` manually, but no luck. `/usr/local/lib` is also part of `ld.conf` and I am running `ubuntu 16.04`.

Comment: When you say it's no longer linked, you mean that lib2 doesn't search for lib1, or that lib2 can't find lib1?

Comment: It cannot find it. If I do ldd liblib2.so in /usr/local/lib it returns not found